# Business Entities, Data Access Layer - Circular Reference

Tags: entity-framework-4, data-access-layer, circular-reference

I am new to EF4 and are trying to follow the guidance as best I can, so I have choosen to go down the POCO route and have put the POCO classes in there own project. I have added repository classes in the DataAccess project and off course the DataAccess project reference the POCO project.

I am currently adding business functionality to the POCO classes and hit a snag where a particular method on one of the POCO objects creates a bunch of other POCO objects, which is cool. BUT, the POCO objects that it creates are already in the database so know I need my BusinessEntity project to reference the DataAccess project which of course is creating a circular reference.

Any guidance in this space would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the method that "creates a bunch of other POCO objects"? This shouldn't happen. POCO methods should be domain/business specific - nothing to do with data. If you start working with data, they are no longer POCO's.

Comment: So I have a "Share" object as in a security. I have implemented a "Split" method which add's a new POCO "Event" object to Share.Events The Event has a type which is an existing record in the DB, it is retrieving this EventType that I need to make a call to the DAL.

Comment: @BenBuckland - you shouldn't have that code there. Your DAL/Repository should set that property. Since your using EF4, you can "eager load" the Events when you grab a share: e.g `var share = ctx.Shares.Include("Events")`, and EF will automatically populate the events.

Comment: @RPM1984 - Once I have added the Event for sure I can return it but what about the creation of the new Event and the associated existing EventType object?

Comment: if your referring to a "new" Event (eg not in database set), then whatever is creating that event should setup the Shares. The POCO's shouldn't be *aware* of themselves. If you have a web page which creates an event, when you submit the form, the server should create the event object and shares and perisist that object via the DAL.

Comment: @RPM1984 I agree with you regarding the new Event but the Event has an EventType which is existing in the DB. So I can create a new Event and 'connect' that Event to the Share, but how do I connect the EventType to the Event given that the EventType is an object that has already been persisted to the DB?

Comment: @BenBuckland - is "EventType" a seperate entity in your EDMX? It's getting very hard to visualize what is going on. Adding a screenshot of your EDMX designer to this question would help immensely.

Comment: @RPM1984 - Yes, it is a seperate entity. Let me get you a screen grab.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding your issue, but it kind of sounds like you may want to go with a DTO (Data Transfer Objects) type route.  I am new to EF myself but am currently working on an EF, WCF, WinForms project.  I have contract objects for my WCF service that I use to send data back to the client.  I map properties from my EF Entities to my DTO objects in my business layer.  I use DTOs because my client does not need all the properties of the EF Entity.  [Try this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnforum/archive/2010/07/13/community-goodies-n-tier-application-patterns-in-entity-framework.aspx). I found some really good stuff regarding project structure.  Hope this helps.